# Topic Outline links not working on documentation page in Firefox or IE

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, firefox

1. Browse here: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/26/keywords
2. Click on one of the Topic Outline links on the right hand side of the page (e.g. `volatile`).
3. Nothing happens.

Problem occurs for me in Firefox 53.0 and IE 11. In Chrome and Edge, it works fine.